# Limit buffer list to current tab

Tags: buffers, tabbed-user-interface

Is there a way to list the buffers specific to the tab that is open currently in vim or macvim?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code defines a new command :LsByTab that parses the output of :ls and groups it by tabs. You can call the command with an exclamation mark and/or the flags supported by :ls.

```
"
" Get the output of :ls as a List of lines.
"
function! s:LsOutput(bang, args)
    redir => ls_output
    exe 'silent ls' . a:bang a:args
    redir END
    return split(ls_output, "\n")
endfunction

"
" Group the output of :ls by tabs and print it.
"
function! LsByTab(bang, args)
    let ls_output = s:LsOutput(a:bang, a:args)

    " Iterate over all tabs.
    for tab in gettabinfo()
        echo '===== tab' tab.tabnr '====='
        " Get the buffer numbers for the current tab.
        let buffers = tabpagebuflist(tab.tabnr)
        " Construct a regular expression that matches the buffer numbers
        " at the start of the lines of the :ls output.
        let buffers_pat = '^\s*\(' . join(buffers, '\|') . '\)\>'
        " Filter the lines from the :ls output so that only the lines for
        " the buffers of the current tab remain.
        let tab_buffers = filter(copy(ls_output), 'v:val =~ buffers_pat')
        " Print the info for the current tab.
        echo join(tab_buffers, "\n")
    endfor
endfunction

command! -bang -nargs=? LsByTab call LsByTab(<q-bang>, <q-args>)
```

Answer (score 6):

The following code will give you the file names for the current tab (if the buffer in a window is connected to a file):

```
" Get the buffer numbers of all windows on the current tab
let buffers = tabpagebuflist(tabpagenr())
" Get the name of each buffer
let buffernames = map(copy(buffers), {key, val -> bufname(val)})
" Print the buffer names
echo buffernames
```

This needs a sufficiently new version of Vim, which supports lamdas.

Comment: You can replace the 2 first commands by `let buffers = tabpagebuflist()`. [`:h tabpagebuflist()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#tabpagebuflist%28%29)

Comment: @statox Thank you, done. When searching for an adequate function in the docs I had only looked for something matching `get*()`. :-(

Comment: Lambda free version: `let buffernames = map(copy(buffers), 'bufname(v:val)')`. Also you can see function group by category via `:h function-list`

Comment: This only tells you the number of the currently open buffers though. 
I was hoping something more like `ls` command that groups buffers by which tab they are in.

Comment: @tushar You should update your question to make this more clear. See my second answer for a solution that matches your reworded question.

Comment: `let buffernames = map(copy(buffers), {key, val -> bufname(val)})` 
Jurgen's script is not working in gvim 7.4, especially above line. But this is working (Peter's suggestion) `let buffernames = map(copy(buffers), 'bufname(v:val)')` Thank you, it's really helpful.